# Closure and Interior of Arithmetic Progression

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to figure out and prove what the interior and closure of A where A is all even integers for the topologies on the integers with the following topologies would be.

K must be a nonnegative integer

First: $B(a, k) = \{a + (3^k)m \mid m  \epsilon \mathbb{Z}\}$
Based on intuition, I think  $Int A = \phi$, but I have no idea how to prove this.
I also think $Cl A = \mathbb{Z}$ but have no idea if this is right or how to prove it.

Second: $B(a, k) = \{ a + (2^k)m \mid m  \epsilon \mathbb{Z} \}$
I think $Int A = B(0,1)$ but I do not know how to prove this.
I think $Cl A = B(0,1)$ as well since $B(0,1)$ is open since $\mathbb{Z} - B(0,1) = B(1,1)$ which is open. Is this correct? How do prove $\mathbb{Z} - B(0,1) = B(1,1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First case: if $a \in A$, and $B(a,k) \subseteq A$for some $k$, then $B(a,k) \ni a+3^k \in A$ which is a contradiction as $a$ is even and $3^k$ is always odd (also true for $k=0$) so $a+3^k$ is odd, so not in $A$. So no point $a \in A$ is an interior point of $A$ in the topology with these local bases. Hence $\operatorname{int}(A)=\emptyset$.

$\operatorname{cl}(A) = \Bbb Z$ because if $a$ is odd and $B(a,k)$ is any local base set, $a + 3^k \in A \cap B(a,k)$ and so every basic neighbourhood of $a$ intersects $A$.

Second case: If $a$ is even then all numbers of the form $a+m\cdot 2^k$ are also even (sum of even numbers) and if $a$ is odd, so are all $a+m \cdot 2^k$ as well. So both $A$ and $\mathbb{Z}\setminus A$ are open, and so both are closed as well (so $\operatorname{int}(A)=A=\operatorname{cl}(A)$)